# powershell command to determine theme used by webs or a site collection

Tags: powershell

Is there a powershell command to determine the name of the theme is used by webs under a site collection? If yes, is there a powershell way to dissassociate the theme from a web or all the webs under a given site collection?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? I ask because you can't disassociate a theme...you can apply a new one.  This can be done thru the UI or via the OM.  The UI has the added benefit of cascading the change down to any subsites that are inheriting from their parent site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the object model via Powershell. There are no native cmdlets.

```
$site = Get-SPsite "url"
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$theme = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.ThmxTheme]::GetManagedThemes($site)
```

You can then loop thru the collection to see all the themes assigned.

You can call various methods to manage your themes in this way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.thmxtheme_members.aspx

These are disposable object so you need to manage them or use the Start / Stop-SPAssigment

Vijai has posted some other examples for working with themes:
http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Code/remove-sharepoint-site-theme-powershell-318.aspx

http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Code/change-sharepoint-site-theme-powershell-319.aspx

Comment: $site=Get-SPSite "http://Sales.NortelNetwork.com/NW"
$web=$site.OpenWeb()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.ThmxTheme]::RemoveThemeFromWeb($web,$false)
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
I went to sp manager and the old theme is still in there. hmm
$site.Dispose()

Answer (score 0):

Gary Lapointe's STSADM extensions might be useful [here](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2008/01/apply-theme), albeit for 2007.  It looks like there's a 2010 command available [here](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/05/announcing-my-sharepoint-2010-powershell-cmdlets-stsadm-commands-now-available-for-download/).

[Here](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2010/09/automatically-apply-theme-to-a-sharepoint-foundation-2010-subsite/) is a reference on how to set it automatically with code, it could probably be tweaked to reset it to Default.